# Custom loss function for predicting numeric output

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I want my keras network to predict a numeric output in the range 60..200. In my experience, just outputting a sigmoid*140+60 or similarperforms very poorly in this case, and converting it to a class can be better.

However, I'm struggling with defining the loss function. Obviously predicting a nearby class is better, and should be penalized less.

Example code below. Network will obviously be more complex and likely partly convolutional, but this is just getting things started.

The current code gives an error:  "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None') and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices". I guess that makes sense, since backpropagation limits what can be done, but I'm not sure how to go around properly designing and debugging loss functions.

```
classes = np.array(range(60,200,5))
nc = classes.shape[0]
def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
  pred_class = K.argmax(y_pred,axis=1)
  return K.sqrt( K.sum( K.square( classes[pred_class] - y_true ) ) )

in1 = Input(shape=(77,))
mid = Dense(50, activation='tanh')( in1 ) 
out = Dense(nc, activation='softmax')( mid ) 
model = Model(inputs=in1, outputs=out)
model.add_loss( myloss(sbp, out) )
```

Comment: Is this a classificatin or a regression problem? Do you want the range [60, 200] to be continuous or discrete (just integers)?

Comment: It's technically continuous, but an RMSE of ~5 would be insanely good, and reference values are noisy and rounded to integers.

Comment: The problem you describe is an ordinal regression problem. There are multiple papers on loss functions for ordinal regression in machine learning. As you say, the idea is to penalize larger deviations more, which is not the case in the crossentropy loss commonly used for classification. You could have a look at this github repo (I have no experience with using it myself): https://github.com/JHart96/keras_ordinal_categorical_crossentropy

Comment: That works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is an ordinal regression problem. There are multiple papers on loss functions for ordinal regression in machine learning. As you say, the idea is to penalize larger deviations more, which is not the case in the crossentropy loss commonly used for classification. You could have a look at this github repo (I have no experience with using it myself): https://github.com/JHart96/keras_ordinal_categorical_crossentropy